# Implementing a new 'ISignatureFactory' with EC type

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to create a new ISignatureFactory for an external HSM, using an EC key.

While I can't find EC mentioned when implementing this object:

```
  public object AlgorithmDetails => new AlgorithmIdentifier(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha256WithRsaEncryption);
```

'PkcsObjectIdentifiers' doesn't have Sha256 with EC option.

Also, when implementing 'ISigner', I wrote EC this way:

```
public string AlgorithmName => "SHA-256withECDSA";
```

What can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
  public object AlgorithmDetails => new AlgorithmIdentifier(X9ObjectIdentifiers.ECDsaWithSha256);
```

Instead of "PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha256WithRsaEncryption".